# Get AD-Computer not like distinguished name

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of computers from AD excluding some computers which are not in use anymore.
Here is my code:

```
$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where { 
    $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike @("*server1*","*Server2*")
} | Select-Object Name
```

I am trying to put the computers which I was to exclude in an array instead of using

```
-and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*serverIwantToExclude*"
```

Can you guys give me any idea on how I could amend it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-notlike` does not support collections on the right-hand side (RHS). A similarly intended approach is to use `-notmatch`, which is a regex string:

```
$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * |
    Where { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch 'server1|Server2'} |
        Select-Object Name
```

---

If you want your server names in a list first, you can create a regex string from that.

```
$serverdown = 'server1','server2'
$regex = $serverdown -join '|'
$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * |
    Where { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $regex} |
        Select-Object Name
```

---

If you do not anchor your regex strings, it looks for the regex match anywhere within the target string (effectively having surrounding wildcards). `|` is an alternation (an effective `OR`).

There are other operators that support collections like `-contains`, `-in`, `-notin`, and `-notcontains`. However, they must match exactly and cannot use wildcards.

Comment: Hi thanks it works..

$serverdown = @('server1','server2')
is there a way to put in in an array like the below ? 
$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * |
    Where { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $serverdown} |
        Select-Object Name

Comment: Yes. I added how to adapt this to using an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `-inotin` operator if you know the full name of the servers you wish to exclude, meaning you can not use a wildcard or regex with the `-inotin` operator. If this is the case and you know the names I recommend using the `Name` property of the `ADComputer` object.

```bsh
[string[]] $excludedServers = 'server1','server2'

$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where { 
    $_.DistinguishedName -like "*Computers*" -and $_.Name -inotin $excludedServers 
} | Select-Object Name
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

another way to exclude them is to add all those computers to a group and exclude it

#Provide DN of the group

$groupname = "CN=groupname,OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=COM"

get-adcomputer -filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*Windows*")} | -properties * | ?{([string]$_.memberof -notmatch $groupname)} | select name, lastlogondate